# Forward slashes: are they acceptable in Commonwealth English prose?

Tags: punctuation, slash

In Commonwealth English is it acceptable to write this in a magazine article:

> If there are there any nearby towns**/**villages …

Comment: As an editor, I would not accept that construction and would ask for it to be changed (or would just change it myself). I especially dislike the use of "and/or"; in most instances, it is lazy writing.

Comment: I agree about *and/or* but find the slash to be helpful in technical writing, usually annoying in other writing. (This is a US perspective.)

Comment: Is there really a standard called "Commonwealth English"?

Answer (score 3):

Punctuation of that kind would be unhelpful in any kind of English. It is much clearer to write *If there are there any nearby towns **or** villages* or *If there are there any nearby towns **and** villages*, as appropriate. What, incidentally, do you mean by ‘Commonwealth English’?

Answer (score 1):

Using a forward slash is acceptable as a typographical symbol in place of "or". Overuse has the unfortunate consequence of reduced flow and/or writer appearing unsure of himself/herself.